# Windows 10 download won't start

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-10

I'm on geniuine Windows 8.1.

I've been trying to get this to work forever now. According to the installer, it's downloading but when I click "View progress" it opens Windows Update which says "Looking for updates" and then after a few seconds Windows Update just force closes, causing everything to flash and explorer.exe to restart. I do not know why I cannot get this to download, I've restarted my computer several times and it just does the same thing everytime I try. Is anyone experiencing the same thing as me, and is there a fix? If I open Windows update from the control panel it just shows that it's actually doing nothing, not even searching for updates.

Comment: I know, but surely since it's out it shouldn't be hard to download? Other people in this residence could download it just fine, except me.

Comment: Have you tried to download the .ISO and use that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

1. Launch an  elevated command prompt. (Open the Charms, click Search, type "cmd" without quotes, and press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.)
2. Type: `wuauclt.exe /updatenow`. Press enter.

Check Windows Update to see if it's downloading. If not, make sure that Automatic Updates are enabled. If it's still not working, run [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971058) troubleshooter, then try again.